# Can a tube with a bottom (a closed end) can be expressed as a " bottomed tube"?

Tags: nouns

I am searching for a simple word for describing a tube having one closed end and one open end, such as a test tube. After googled, I found the expression "bottomed tube", but it seems this is usually used by non-natives. I would like to know if this is correct (although it may sound strange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard it before, so I suspect it is not a common or recognised term. I don't see anything grammatically wrong with "closed tube", although the words alone do not fully convey what you describe. As with anything without a common name, if you describe it fully once, then hopefully your audience will know what you are talking about when you refer back to it by the name you gave it.

The dictionary gives multiple definitions for "tube", including:

- a long, hollow cylinder of metal, plastic, glass, etc. *for holding or transporting something*
- a flexible metal or plastic container sealed at one end *and having a screw cap at the other, for holding a semi-liquid substance ready for use*.

Both of these definitions suggest that the tube is "closed", either at one end, or both. I can think of examples where the word "tube" is used for a closed container - for example, a *tube of toothpaste*, or *a tube of glue*.

However, you might be best using a term like "*cylindrical container*" if you want your audience to immediately grasp from those two words that it is capable of holding or containing something.